# Rx Java observable transformation

Tags: java, android, rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2

How to convert `Observable<List<A>>` to `List<A>` without using `blockingFirst()`?

I have a function which returns `Observable<List<A>>`. This returned value must be assigned to attribute of `class B` like `b.listA = List<A>`.

But currently I'm getting `b.listA = Observable<List<A>>`. 
If I use `b.listA = Observable<List<A>>.blockingFirst()` then it solves the problem. But its not a good way of implementation

Comment: @Raghunandan not similar bro. It still returns Observable, i just want the data type

Answer (score 2):

> I have a function which returns Observable>. This returned
>   value must be assigned to attribute of class B like b.listA = List

`Subscribe` the observable. If the emitter works correctly, your `onNext` will the get the value (`List<A>`), there you can assign it.

Comment: the above question is for the nested part where the attribute is dependent on the dao

Comment: I am not sure what your comment means . Could you rephrase ?